# How do I make Firefox and Chrome honor absolute sizes?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, layout, printing

I am the author of the [PasswordCard](http://www.passwordcard.org/) web site. It has an image of a password card (a low tech way of generating passwords), which is supposed to be credit card sized, on it. The image is included on the page thusly:

```html
<img src="/generatecard.do?number=756b9bb158f9564b&cookie=ok7q0sqrym26" style="width: 85.6mm; height: 53.98mm" alt="Picture of PasswordCard">
```

As you can see it has an absolute width and height in an attempt to show and print it at exactly credit card size. When I made this a couple of years ago, this worked; every browser printed it at exactly the right size. However now something appears to have changed. Both Firefox and Chrome now print this too large by something like 5% to 10%. Internet Explorer 8 still prints it at the correct size; I have not checked a newer version of IE and would not be surprised if IE11 or Edge also print it too large.

I can't figure out why this happens. I'm not setting any scaling options nor are any such options enabled in the printer settings. I have tried to research the problem but it's hard to google for. I haven't found any information about changes in CSS or something like that which would explain this. I have seen hints that Chrome's way of printing by rendering the page as a PDF first might cause problems like this, but it also occurs in Firefox, so it doesn't seem likely to be the problem. Also it usually causes things to be printed too small whereas in this case it is printed too large.

I'm in Europe so I'm printing on A4 paper.

My questions are:

1. What has changed in web browsers like Firefox and Chrome in the last couple of years that would explain this?
2. How can I force web browsers to print an image at a specific absolute size (disregarding any manual or explicit scaling by the user of course)?

Many thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Can you provide your code here?

Comment: @TOM Which code? The html code for the page is probably easiest accessed by just following the link to the site. The Java code which generates the page isn't secret, but I don't think it could be relevant.

Comment: I think that Windows in general calculates real world measures via calibration in display settings, there are custom sizing option swhich display an on-screen ruler. The default dot-pitch for Windows in the 90's was 72dpi - Macs have always been 96dpi. I would presume that if you attach a 96dpi monitor to a 72dpi config, you'd end up with larger millimetres. There's no way therefore to guarantee on-screen size. On-paper size is guaranteed however. You could try using a smaller card onscreen so that it looks compact on all devices, and use a separate print stylesheet.

Comment: @MarkRabjohn I appreciate that on-screen sizes are harder to guarantee; I'm fine with that. The problem is specifically the print size, which used to be correct, but now is no longer. Specifying the size in absolute units as I am doing should always be correct in print and good enough on screen, so there's no need to use a separate print style sheet (although I do in fact use one, just to hide elements I don't want printed).